# local variable is undefined, althought I assigned it a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm not exactly new to programming, so I'm baffled why after assigning a value to a variable that's declared with the var key word, that when I call the function I get a reference error sum is "not defined". It doesn't make sense. I declared sum with var and assigned it a value of 0. I'm creating a function that returns the number of zeros in an array. Here is the snippet of code that I'm working on for my homework. I'd appreciate any suggestions, please.

```
numZero = function (a) {
    var sum = a[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i += 1) {
        if (sum < 1) {
            sum += a[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
};

alert(numZero([2, 8, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1]));
```

Comment: It [works](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/e275skx0/)

Comment: The code mentioned works, it shows an alert with value 2

Comment: Can you produce your error on jsfiddle ?

Comment: If it works why am I getting the reference error sum is no defined.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or use stacksnippet to show us the not working example.

Comment: what is jsfiddle? Is that a program, like jslint?

Comment: _"If it works why am I getting the reference error sum is no defined."_ You tell us. The code you posted functions without error.

Comment: _I'm creating a function that returns the number of zeros in an array_, but the code in question is returning sum. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nthdprgr/)

Comment: [Click here to create a new JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Right now I'm researching what jsfiddle is. I went to the website. I'm trying to learn how to use it. Thanks,

Comment: It shoud be three (3) because there are 3 zeros.

Comment: @swydell DID you check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nthdprgr/), on my previous comment? No! Then check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code runs without error, but it doesn't return the number of 0's in a array. The reason for this is that you set `sum` to the value of the first element in the array: `var sum = a[0]`

Then, in the for loop you check if sum is less than 1, which in this case it never is because 2 is always greater than 1, so the code in the if statement never runs.

Lastly, even if it did run, every time a zero is found, it would add 0 to to sum because you're doing `sum += a[i]` which `a[i]` is supposed to be zero if this code runs.

I fixed up your code to run properly:

```
var numZero = function (a) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
        if (a[i] === 0) {
            sum += 1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Comment: Basically, sum gets set to 0. Then we run the for loop over the entire array that's passed in starting at the beginning - var i = 0;. Then we check if the value of the current array element we're on is strictly equal to 0. If so, we add 1 to sum. If not, we check the next number. The reason I didn't do a[i] < 1 is because all negative numbers are also less than 1 which could give an inaccurate count if someone uses them. At the end we return sum.

Answer (score 1):

```
numZero = function (a) {
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    if (a[i] == 0) {
        sum++;
    }
}
return sum;
};

alert(numZero([2, 8, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

First this function doesn't return the amount of zero values in the array. And the maybe sum is undefined because your are passing an empty array as a argument .
I just notice that you are missing car keyword on your numZero function definition

Comment: The way I understand it is that my argument is what I'm passing when I call the function. I don't see how that can be empty. This is how I understand it. Parameters are inside the parenthesis of the function. The arguments are what I put inside the function when I call it. But I'm probably missing something here. I'm open minded to learning. Thanks for your suggestion and help.

Comment: you are in the right place , look you are missing the var keyword in your numZero definition